# Using Object.create in [google-apps-script] script file in Chrome on a Chromebook

Tags: google-apps-script, object-create

I have been trying to use Object.create in a gas script file.  Object.create is defined but doesn't seem to return a useful object.

```
function createOject() {
  var o = Object.create({}, { p: { value: 42 } })
  Logger.log(o.p); //logs 42.0 as expected
  var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
  db.save(o);  //o still shows up as empty {} in the debugger and 
               //won't save to data store
  showTable(); //logs nothing
}
```

This code works fine:

```
  function createOject() {
    var o = {p: 42};
    Logger.log(o.p); //logs 42.0 as expected
    var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
    db.save(o);  //o shows up as an object {p: 42} in the debugger and 
                 //saves to the the data store as expected
    showTable(); //logs {p: 42} as expected
}
```

So, although Object.create is defined it doesn't seem to work as expected.  Is this a bug or am I  missing something?

Answer (score 2):

ScriptDb doesn't save non-enumerable properties. Object.create() uses the [Object.defineProperties() syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), which defaults to non-enumerable. If you change your code to this:

```
var o = Object.create({}, { p: { value: 42, enumerable: true } })
```

then it should work as you expected.

Object.getOwnPropertyNames() returns both enumerable and non-enumerable properties.

Incidentally, this is not just for ScriptDb... non-enumerable properties are never preserved when passing an object to an Apps Script API function, by design.

Answer (score 0):

An update for 2021*. Object.create(your_obj) still does not perform the way you might expect in Google Apps Script because it does not save non-enumerable properties (sic. Corey G.).

With Google Apps Script's move to the V8 engine, you can now take advantage of some modern Javascript methods.

You could consider using the [Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) (example 1) to generate a new object based on one or more objects or try [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) (example 2) to add to a current object. Both approaches generate a shallow clone of the objects.

```
function test(){
  const a = {name:"Yagi", species:"goat"}
  const b = {hobby:"coding", friendly:true}



  //Example 1
  const c = {...a,...b}

  console.log("c: ",c)

  //Example 2
  Object.assign(a, b); //Assigns 'b' (or multilpes objects) to 'a'

  console.log("a: ", a)
}
```

Incidentally, [scriptDB was depreciated in 2014](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2014/05/deprecating-scriptdb-and-domain-service.html).

**Note: This is question was the closest match to the search "Object.create() Google Apps Script". This updated answer responds to users searching for this problem.*